# Unix run a script with -help option

Tags: unix

I have the below script that is expected to work when the user invokes `sh <scriptName> <propertyfile>` It does work when I provide this at the dollar prompt. However, I am having two issues with the script.

1. If I provide just one argument, ie if I do - `sh <scriptName>`, I see the below error -

   ```
   my-llt-utvsg$ sh temp.sh
   Usage temp.sh
   ```
2. When I do -help, I see the below error -

   ```
   my-llt-utvsg$ sh tmp.sh -help
   -help does not exist
   ```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please advise? I am a software developer that very rarely needs to do shell scripting, so please go easy on me ;)

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="system.properties"
FILE=$1
if [ ! -f $FILE ];
then
   echo "$FILE does not exist"
exit
fi
usage ()
{
  echo "Usage $0 $FILE" 
  exit
}
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]
then
  usage
fi
if [ "$1" = "-help" ] ; then
echo ""
echo '############ HELP PROPERTIES ############    '
echo ""
echo 'Blah.'
exit
```

Comment: @downvoter - Can you please tell me why have you downvoted?

Comment: If one of these answers helped you solve this it would be good to consider accepting one, this will help the community know this question has already been solved.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your

```
if [ "$1" = "-help" ] ; then
```

check is not working is that it only checks `$1` or the first argument.

Try instead:

```
for var in "$@"
do
    if [ "$var" = "-help" ] ; then
        echo ""
        echo '############ HELP PROPERTIES ############    '
        echo ""
        echo 'Blah.'
    fi
done
```

Which will loop over each argument and so will run if any of them are -help.

Comment: +1, very good solution. I was just going to give the same solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try this as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=()

function show_help_info_and_exit {
    echo ""
    echo '############ HELP PROPERTIES ############    '
    echo ""
    echo 'Blah.'
    exit
}

function show_usage_and_exit {
    echo "Usage: $0 file" 
    exit
}

for __; do
    if [[ $__ == -help ]]; then
        show_help_info_and_exit
    elif [[ -f $__ ]]; then
        FILES+=("$__")
    else
        echo "Invalid argument or file does not exist: $__"
        show_usage_and_exit
    fi
done

if [[ ${#FILES[@]} -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo "Invalid number of file arguments."
    show_usage_and_exit
fi

echo "$FILES"
```